# Linking Source Directory to Map Layout in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I've seen it done before in MapInfo layouts where the directory of a saved workspace has been linked to and displayed in the map layout window.

If this is possible in QGIS, then how is it done?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you mean by "directory of a saved workspace"?

Comment: @Erik I saw someone who had been able to customise MapInfo a titleblock so it automatically picked up the location of the workspace file (i.e C:\Projects\GIS). I thought it would be a really great feature to integrate into some templates I'm working on but I don't know where/how to do it in QGIS.

Comment: Workspace file = project file?

Comment: @Erik Yeah the project file

Answer (score 2):

Both the variables

`@project_path`

and

`@project_folder`

will work fine. You can access these simply via the field calculator or add them to text fields e.g. in the map composer.